# Regular Expression and Pattern

Tags: java, regex

MP (((1.1 1.2, 2.1 1.5),(3.1 4.1)),((8.1 6.2, 2.5 4.5),(3.8 4.9)),((7.1 6.2, 2.5 5.5),(3.8 4.9)))

In Java how i can split them to get double values. What pattern and reqex would be ?
but not only doubles, with index of bracket layer

thank you.

i will appreciate if Output is like following way

bracket 1
 sub bracket 1 :

point 1 :1.1 1.2

point 2 :2.1 1.5

sub bracket 2:

point 1 :3.1 4.1

bracket 2

sub bracket 1 :

point 1 :8.1 6.2

point 2 :2.5 4.5

sub bracket 2:

point 1 :3.8 4.9

...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Can you provide some precise sample output to match your sample input?  It's unclear precisely what you need.

Comment: i will appreciate if Output is like following way
bracket 1   
 sub bracket 1 : 

   point 1 :1.1 1.2

   point 2 :2.1 1.5

 sub bracket 2:

   point 1 :3.1 4.1

bracket 2  

 sub bracket 1 : 

   point 1 :8.1 6.2

   point 2 :2.5 4.5

 sub bracket 2:

   point 1 :3.8 4.9

...

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you only want to get a list of the doubles, you can use something like this:

```
String input = "(((1.1 1.2, 2.1 1.5),(3.1 4.1)),((8.1 6.2, 2.5 4.5),(3.8 4.9)),((7.1 6.2, 2.5 5.5),(3.8 4.9)))";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+").matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    double d = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group());
    System.out.println(d);  //or alternatively, add to a list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to split on any of these non-digit characters -- sounds like they don't matter at all, just the values:

```
value.split("[\\(\\), ]+")
```

Then parse each `String` with `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: That would leave `"MP"`. IMO, a `Pattern+Matcher` would be more appropriate.

Comment: A negation might be even easier: `.split("[^\\d.]+")`.  But either way you'll have to deal with empty strings since the input *starts* with a delimiter.

Comment: Oops good point. @Mark I think your answer is better. Do you have to escape the '.'? Maybe not in braces, haven't tried it.

Comment: @Sean: If it's in a character class (braces), it's not treated as a special character, so no.  It wouldn't hurt to escape it, but it's unnecessary.

Comment: if it is like this in following "name"=>"Ack","shop"="get","opening"=>"Tu-Sa 09:30-12:00, 15:15-19:00"